# why do we need to define data source property for datagridviewcell as well as datagridviewColumn in c# while hosting a custom cell in datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I have searched around for this but I can not find any reason because on MSDN there is an example of hosting datetime picker and numeric updown control where they alter only it's view but I need to pass datasource as we pass in combobox .
I already tried by defining datasource property in `dayagridviewColumn` but failed. And finally I checked Classes : `datagridviewcomboboxcell` and `datagridviewcomboboxColumn`, where they have defined datasource property in both the class.

Comment: Your question is formatted so strange.... I don't understand what you want. But I've never been in the situation where I need to give multiple things 1 datasource to actually show it...

Comment: Where is URL that you are referring to?  A Column is only need when you are binding to an object that has columns.  When you have an object the doesn't contain column you do not need to specify a column.

Comment: [link](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/WinForms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewComboBoxCell@cs/1/DataGridViewComboBoxCell@cs) Combobox Cell  and here is the code for datagridviewcomboboxColumn      [link](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/WinForms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewComboBoxColumn@cs/1305376/DataGridViewComboBoxColumn@cs)